# Simple Mathematics equation

Tags: arithmetic

My friend shared me an mathematics equation which is following
    $$3+3\cdot3-3\cdot0=?$$
What is the answer of this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order in which to apply operations:

- Parentheses (innermost to outermost)
- Exponents
- Multiplication/Division (applied from left to right).
- Addition/Subtraction (applied from left to right).

$$3+3\cdot 3-3\cdot 0= 3 + 9 - 3\cdot 0 = 3 + 9 - 0 = 12 - 0 = 12$$

However, in those cases where the intent might be ambiguous, it's always wise to use parentheses. That way, you save a lot of people the trouble of trying to read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally accepted that we should do multiplications first, therefore I would say it is $3+(3\cdot3)-(3\cdot0)=3+9-0=12$. However the main issue here is which convention we should accept.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $12$. Please see [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Answer (score 0):

$3+3\cdot 3-3\cdot 0=3(1+3-0)=3(4)=12$

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the BODMAS rule for order of operation (Bracket open Division Multiplication Addition Subtraction )

So your expression becomes :

$$ 3+ 3\cdot 3 - 3\cdot 0 \Rightarrow  3 + 9 - 0 \Rightarrow 12 $$